# Search the keyboard shortcuts of eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse shows a list of shortcuts when clicking on `Help->Key Assist...` (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>. How can I search this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I learned that when in the window displaying all the shortcuts one can just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> again and it takes you to the key shortcuts preferences page, where there is a text box to search the keybindings.